# How do I know if an C program's executable is run in foreground or background?

Tags: c, linux, unix, solaris

In my C program I want to know if my executable is run in foreground like this

```
$./a.out
```

or like this

```
$./a.out &
```

Comment: Remember a program can switch between fg and bg as the user wishes (in bash: ctrl-z to suspend a fg process, `bg` command to run in bg, can be moved back to fg, etc.).

Comment: @Roger Pate: SIGTSTP is POSIX, not just limited to bash.

Comment: @Tim: I tried to word the example so it had very little chance of being misunderstood, rather than being as general as possible.

Comment: Why the vote to close? This is definitely a C question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are the foreground job,

```
getpgrp() == tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO)
```

or `STDIN_FILENO` or `STDERR_FILENO` or whichever file descriptor you're attached to your controlling terminal by.  (If you're not sure, `open("/dev/tty")` will always get you a file descriptor to your controlling terminal, if one exists.)

This is what [openssh](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/progressmeter.c?rev=HEAD) does, and is a bit easier than handling `SIGTTIN/SIGTTOU` if you just want a quick check.

On the other hand, you may have been backgrounded

```
$ ./a.out
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./a.out
$ bg
[1]+ ./a.out &
```

or foregrounded

```
$ fg
./a.out
```

at any point in time.  You cannot expect that you can check this once and it will still be true (or false) later.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Bash Reference Manual: Job Control Basics](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Basics):

> Background processes are those whose process group id differs from the terminal's; such processes are immune to keyboard-generated signals. Only foreground processes are allowed to read from or write to the terminal. Background processes which attempt to read from (write to) the terminal are sent a SIGTTIN (SIGTTOU) signal by the terminal driver, which, unless caught, suspends the process.

So the solution is to install a signal handler for `SIGTTIN` and then try to read from `stdin` (turn buffering off or it will block). If you get "0 bytes read" back, then you're running in the foreground.

[EDIT] Note that the status of a process can change. You can use the job control commands of the shell (Ctrl-Z, `bg`, `fg` and `jobs`) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this is not possible and usually not necessary either.

Please explain *why* you want to do this.

Comment: Say my process is doing a process intensive job and wants to print a status bar like thing till the calculation is complete by printing '#' via a signal handler of SIGALRM. If my process is run in background, I don't want to print the '#'s . That is where I wanted to differentiate.

Comment: Simply add a --quiet flag and programs that don't want output should call it as ./a.out --quiet. See the getopt() manpages.

Comment: There is precedent for this: for example, scp transfers files in the foreground and the background, but it only updates the status bar when it is in the foreground.

Comment: scp has several config values and command line parameters that control the status but AFAIR there is no status bar by default (i rarely use scp so i might be wrong). Anyways: Why create a complex solution to a simple problem? If the caller doesn't want a status bar (maybe even when the program is in foreground) he adds a parameter and it's done. Simple Problem, simple Solution. If you want the opposite behaviour just name the parameter --progress and invert the show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

[invalid]
IIRC, getppid() (on *nix systems) will give you the parent id.  if it is 0, the 'console' is your parent and so you are running in the background.
[/invalid]

[edit]

```
int devtty;
if ((devtty = open ("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)) < 0)
   printf ("daemon\n");
```

note that this is only valid on *nix systems (and then only if nobody has deleted /dev/tty -- for whatever reason)
[/edit]

Comment: Could not reproduce this with a sample program. getppid() returned the same value for "./a.out" and "./a.out &"

Comment: I doubt that getppid() can return 0. It will either return 1 (if you're detached from the console and the kernel made you a child of the init process) or the PID of the bash shell which started you.

Comment: `/dev/tty` is openable even if you're backgrounded, as long as you still have a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a possibility that you have more than one process
   running in the background:

```
$ jobs
[1]   Stopped                 teamviewer
[2]-  Stopped                 vim
[3]+  Stopped                 firefox
```

- use: `fg %2` to send the vim process back to foreground.
- To send the last process back to foreground simply use: `fg` with no 
  arguments.
- You can also type % process_name to resume the stopped process.

**To suspend the process running in the background**, use:

```
kill -19 %job_id.
```

The `-19` signal is SIGSTOP (the signal sent by Ctrl - Z) .

***you can always see the list by typing*** `kill -l`

**Moving jobs between background / foreground:**

If you have already typed a command and forgot to use the `&`, you can put a foreground job into the background by typing `^Z (CTRL-Z)` to suspend the job, followed by `bg`, to put it into the background:

```
$ sleep 99
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 99
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 99 &
```

You can list the jobs of the current shell using the `jobs` command.

Just remember that "exiting shell" affects jobs as well:

- Jobs running in the background when the shell exits are left running.
- Jobs that are paused (“Stopped”) when the shell exits are terminated.

**Sending signals to jobs and processes**

You can send signals, including termination signals, to jobs that are started from the current shell using job numbers using %(JOBID) instead of process numbers(PID):

```
$ kill %1
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 99
```

To send signals to processes or jobs that are not started from the current shell, you first need to use `ps` to find their process numbers(PID).

You can refer to this link: 
[processes and jobs](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12f/notes/770_processes_and_jobs.html)

The general job control commands in Linux are:

- **jobs** - list the current jobs
- **fg** - resume the job that's next in the queue
- **fg** %[number] - resume job [number]
- **bg** - Push the next job in the queue into the background
- **bg** %[number] - Push the job [number] into the background
- **kill** %[number] - Kill the job numbered [number]
- **kill** -[signal] %[number] - Send the signal [signal] to job number [number]
- **disown** %[number] - disown the process(no more terminal will be owner), so command will be alive even after closing the terminal.

That's pretty much all of them. Note the % infront of the job number in the commands - this is what tells kill you're talking about jobs and not processes.