# How can I tell if a child is asking for stdin? How do I tell it to stop that?

Tags: c, exec, fork

In bash when I run a command like `wc &` or `cat &` that wants standard in right away, it returns immediately with

[1]+ Stopped cat

How is this accomplished? How do I stop a program that I started with exec, and how do I know to stop these programs in the first place? Is there some way to tell that these programs want stdin?

Thanks!

PS also, what is the + about? I've always wondered, but that's really hard to google...

Comment: +1 for "hard to google" symbols

Comment: You may find the answers to this question enlightening: [How do I know if an C program's executable is run in foreground or background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425005/how-do-i-know-if-an-c-programs-executable-is-run-in-foreground-or-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setpgid()` manual page explains how this works:

> A session can have a controlling terminal.  At any time, one (and only
>   one) of the process groups in the session can be  the  foreground
>   process group for the terminal; the remaining process groups are in
>   the background.  If a signal is generated from the terminal (e.g.,
>   typing the interrupt key to generate `SIGINT`), that signal is sent to
>   the foreground process group.  (See `termios(3)` for a description of
>   the  characters that generate signals.)  Only the foreground process
>   group may `read(2)` from the terminal; if a background process group
>   tries to `read(2)` from the terminal, then the group is sent a
>   `SIGTSTP` signal, which suspends it.  The `tcgetpgrp(3)` and
>   `tcsetpgrp(3)` functions are used to get/set the foreground process
>   group of the controlling terminal.

So what you want to do is this:

1. When you create a new pipeline, call `setpgid()` to put all the members of the pipeline in a new process group (with the PID of the first process in the pipeline as the PGID).
2. Use `tcsetpgrp()` to manage which process group is in the foreground - if you put a pipeline in the background with `&`, you should make the shell's own process group the foreground process group again.
3. Call `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` and `WUNTRACED` flags to check on the status of child processes - this will inform you when they are stopped by `SIGTSTP`, which will allow you to print a message like bash does.

Comment: You, sir or madam, did it. That is one long manual page, thanks for the reference. I can't help but notice you have 73 pages of answers, but only three questions: that's something! You honour and inspire me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want spawned programs to behave similarly to how the shell works, call `setpgrp()` after forking your child. This will cause the background program to run in its own process group, and therefore have a detached tty. When it tries to do I/O to the console, it will receive SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU signals. The default behaviour of SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU is to stop the process just like SIGSTOP.

As the parent, you can find out whether you have stopped child processes using `waitpid()` and `WUNTRACED`.

Comment: `setpgrp()` is marked as obsolete in POSIX; it has historically had a different signature in SYSV and BSD systems.  `setpgid()` is the preferred interface.

Answer (score 2):

[Edited -- see other answers for the answer to the main question]

The `+` sign simply refers to the current *job*.  Each pipeline of commands (such as `foo | bar | baz`) is a job, which can be referred to using a *jobspec* beginning with the `%` character.  `%1` is job number 1, `%+` is the current job, and `%-` is the previous job.

For more information about jobs, see the [Job Control section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) of the Bash manual.

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong. It should read "from the controlling terminal of the process group" (or something close to that - I forget the exact details), not "from stdin (file descriptor 0)". A perfectly good way to avoid this is to make file descriptor 0 refer to a non-terminal, e.g. by putting `</dev/null` on the command line.

Comment: And it's the default action for `SIGTTIN`, not the shell, that suspends the process. It can be overridden with a signal handler.

Comment: I think this doesn't answer my question, which is about c rather than bash. How is the process suspended, and how do I know it is reading from stdin. Remember, I'm bash. (you go the PS part though! Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system("command &")` in the forked child process and then manually make it exit, if there are no time and priority constraints.